# insert into table without the intersection part

Tags: sql, intersection

In case I have two SQL tables ,table_a and table_b, both are same , except they may contain different data, I want to insert into the table_b all the rows from table_b that does not exist in table_a already, how should the query look like ? The tables contain id1 and id2 columns only.
Please tell me if my question is not clear

```
Insert into table_a ...
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
; with cte_left as
(
select id1+id2
from table_a
where id1+id2 not in (select id1+id2 from table_b)
)

insert into table_b
select * from cte_left
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `EXCEPT` operator:

```
INSERT INTO table_a (id1, id2)
SELECT id1, id2
FROM (
  SELECT id1, id2
  FROM table_b

  EXCEPT

  SELECT id1, id2
  FROM table_a
) except_gry
```

SQL Fiddle demo [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/848c3/1)

Answer (score 0):

```
Insert into table_a ( id1, id2 ) 
select b.id1, b.id2
from table_b b
left outer join table_a a on a.id1 = b.id1 and a.id2 = b.id2
where a.id1 is null
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use not exist in your query:

```
insert into table_a(id1,id2)
select id1,id2 
from table_b 
where not exists(select id1,id2 from table_a)
```